# GraphViz fixedsize=shape not working

Tags: graphviz

The node property `fixedsize=shape` does not seem to be working on my GraphViz graphs.  For example, this:

```
digraph Automaton {
  rankdir=LR
  node [shape=circle fixedsize=shape label=""]
  0;
  1 [shape=doublecircle];
  2 [shape=doublecircle label="HELLO_12345"];
  0 -> { 2 } [label="98 (b)"];
  0 -> { 1 } [label="97 (a)"];
  1 -> { 1 } [label="97 (a)"];
}
```

...produces this:

[image: test.png]

I expected the node labeled HELLO_12345 to be drawn the same size as the other nodes.  I tried adding `fixedsize=shape` to the declaration of that node, to no avail.

When was `fixedsize=shape` added?  The latest version of GraphViz appears to be 2.38, but Ubuntu 14.04 is still at version 2.36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out GraphViz has a [change log](http://www.graphviz.org/ChangeLog.txt).  Who'da thought?  And yes, `fixedsize=shape` was added after version 2.36.0 and before version 2.38.0.  I don't know what the intermediate version that contained this change was called (the log doesn't say) but this probably explains why it doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04.